# VS Code PowerShell Terminal: Removing banner

Tags: terminal, powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to remove the banner of Powershell Terminal in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: See the Images section here on how to embed the image in your post: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation for the Integrated Terminal feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) it's possible to add shell parameters via the settings file.

In this case, you'll want to add the `-NoLogo` parameter.

For example, I updated the existing PowerShell profiles for Windows like this:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": ["-NoLogo"] // <---- this is the addition
        },

        // other profiles here
    }
```

Comment: This works.  But maybe the doc link has been moved to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-profiles

Answer (score 1):

You can open `$profile` with a text editor and type a `cls` in it, it will clear terminal window on every start.

If you don't use VSCode you can create a shortcut with `powershell.exe -NoLogo`.

Comment: oh thanks, i just found our that i can edit the $profile using the command notepad $profile

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Terminal, go to `Settings`, and click on `Add a new Profile` in the left pane at the bottom. Then, duplicate the `Windows Powershell` profile. Be sure to use that profile in `Startup`. Click on the new profile and go to `Command Line` and add `-nologo`, it should look like this:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo
```